# How overflow:hidden works to wrap around floating elements?

Tags: css, css-float

I'm a bit confused when to use overflow:hidden to make sure the the parent element wraps around other elements. I've always used the clear: both; div to do that, but it doesn't make a lot of sense semantically. Can anyone explain how overflow:hidden parent div does it's magic? And when should we prefer this technique over the clear:both method?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overflow of anything but visible creates a new block formatting context which clears the floats.

Answer (score -1):

When we use float : left , the problem with that is when there is enough space for the next element it will come next to the floated element  to avoid that we use clear:both

eg:

```
<style>
#wrapper{
width:500px;
}

#one{
width:100px;
float:left;
}

#two{
width:100px;
float:left;
}

#three{
width:100px;
}

.clearfix{
clear:both;
}

</style>


<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="one"></div>
   <div id="two"></div>
   <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

In the above situation totaly there is 500px space out of that one, two divs took 200px space rest there is 300px space and dv three is just 100 px . So div three will go next to div two as there is enough space. To avoid that just put a div with clear:both after div two

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="one"></div>
   <div id="two"></div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
   <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```